# ModelTranslation, Django Admin and Widgets

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-modeltranslation

I'm using django-modeltranslation to translate one of my model. Everything is fine for now, except that my previous widget isn't working anymore. It tried many things, including this :

```py
class EmailTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'body':
            kwargs['body'] = TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30})
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(EmailTemplateAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)

class TranslatedEmailTemplateAdmin(EmailTemplateAdmin, TabbedTranslationAdmin):
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        field = super(TranslatedEmailTemplateAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        self.patch_translation_field(db_field, field, **kwargs)
        return field
```

According to the [documentation of django-modeltranslation](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html#admin-classes-that-override-formfield-for-dbfield) about this case, it's the proper way to do this.

I'm not asking for a solution for my own problem, because I guess it might be something in my own code that breaks the thing. I'd just like to have an example of using a widget on a field in django admin that uses modeltranslation... Thanks ! :)

Using Django == 1.6.7 and django-modeltranslation==0.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of properly overriding the `formfield_for_dbfield` method of your `ModelAdmin` class. Looks like you missed `kwargs.pop('request', None)` and confused `kwargs['widget']` with `kwargs['body']`

Here is the rewritten method:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'body':
        kwargs.pop('request', None)
        kwargs['widget'] = TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30})
        return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
    return super(EmailTemplateAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```